# How to DRY up $scope-manipulating code across controllers in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dry

Pardon if this question is a total blow-off... Just getting warmed-up into the world angularJS.

I have these two controllers: `seekerController` and `wizardController`...

Inside the `wizardController`, I have a `chat` Scope object, and I have implemented a bunch of functions that are manipulating this `chat` Scope object.

Going back to the other controller now, ( `seekerController` ), I discover that I need to have basically a direct replica of this `chat` Scope object and all the other functions manipulating it as I have inside `wizardController`

The obvious way is just to copy all these into my other controller, and my work is done under a minute, but then I'll have a lot of repeated stuffs everywhere...

So: I'm looking for a way where I can have this(the code) in a single place, but still be able to have access to this `chat` Scope object from both controllers, as well as all the other functions working seamlessly.

### Update - add code samples:

```
//seekerController
angular.module('cg.seeker', [])
    .controller('SeekerController', ['$scope', 'seekerService', 'timeService', 'chatService', '$stateParams', 'toastr',
      function ($scope, seekerService, timeService, chatService, $stateParams, toastr) {
        ...
        // THE CHAT BUSINESS
        $scope.chat = { close: true };
        chatService.unreadCount(function(count){
          $scope.chat.unreadCount = count;
          $scope.$apply();
        });

        chatService.listDialogs( function (dialogList) {
          $scope.chat.dialogList = dialogList.items;
          $scope.$apply();
        } );

        $scope.endChat = function () {
          $scope.chat.close = true;
        }

        $scope.chatBox = function (dialogId, occupants_ids) {
          $scope.chat.opponentId = getOpponentId(occupants_ids);
          chatService.getMessages( dialogId, function (messageList) {
            $scope.chat.messages = messageList.items;
            $scope.chat.close = false;
            $scope.$apply();
          });
        }

        var getOpponentId = function (opponentId) {
          if(typeof(opponentId) != 'object') {
            return opponentId;
          } else {
            return opponentId.filter(function(x) { return x != $scope.seeker.chat_user.chat_id_string; })[0];
          }
        }

        $scope.sendMsg = function (opponentId) {
          var msg = {
            type: 'chat',
            body: $scope.chat.msg,
            extension: {
              save_to_history: 1,
            }
          };

          chatService.sendMsg(opponentId, msg);
          $scope.chat.msg = '';
        }

     ...
```

I now have an exact replica of the above code in a second controller `WizardController`. Exactly same, with no changes... and even a third controller have some of these, though not all.

Comment: A code is worth a thousand words...

Comment: if you have same code in `WizardController` and `seekerController `, then do you really **need** two different controllers. Can't you use a single controller?

Comment: @JyothrilingaK Thanks, but that's not the only piece of code in the controllers... there are more code in each of them that's very very different. only that the snippet above is common to both, and that's what I'm thinking of DRYing out.

Answer (score 1):

The next level of abstraction to angularjs controllers are

- Factory
- Service
- Provider

You could use a service called maybe `chatService` which could contain the common code. You can inject the service into any controller which needs the common functionality and invoke the methods on the `Service`.

Do note that you could use any of the above three options even though I have mentioned just `Service` in the above statement.

EDIT 1:

You could move the common parts of the code from Controller to Service.
For example:- You could move the construction of `msg` object from controller to `chatService`. You controller would be simply -

```
$scope.sendMsg = function (opponentId) {
      chatService.sendMsg(opponentId);
      $scope.chat.msg = '';
    }
```

And your `chatService` would be doing the hard-work.

```
    $chatService.sendMsg = function (opponentId) {
      var msg = {
        type: 'chat',
        body: $scope.chat.msg,
        extension: {
          save_to_history: 1,
        }
      };

      sendMsg(opponentId, msg);
    }
```

After simplifying the `Controller`s you could revisit to see if you could use only one controller instead of 3 as they seem to be doing similar function.

Comment: I actually already have a `chatService` which can be seen as injected into my controller... What I don't know is that scope can be manipulated inside a service? because it's because of the `chat scope` object that I'm having those duplicated codes in my controllers.

Comment: @sundayAdefila Is it feasible to have one Controller with the code merged from all 3 controllers?

Comment: that one controller will be real bloated, doing many stuffs across different templates which are not related, I'm afraid.